# Is there a simpler syntax to initialize multiple variables in initializer?

Tags: python

I hav a class which needs to initialize 4 variables returned by a load() function. And in the future the load may return even more variable values. This is my current way of initializing the Runner class. Is there a more normal way or better way to do this?

```
class Runner(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.first, self.second, self.third, self.mapping = self.load()

    def load():
       ...
     return (first, second, third, mapping)
```

Comment: I'd recommend initializing the attributes as whatever type they'll end up, and use `self.load()` to set the values of those variables. You COULD use `setattr()` in a `for` loop but that's generally not a good idea. You could also try returning a `dict` from `load()` and `self.__dict__ = {**self.__dict__, **self.load()}` but I haven't tried that to confirm.

Comment: To be honest, it's hard for me to think of something simpler than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will have a very large number of such variables, they should not be variables but keys in a dictionary. The way you're going, you'll have to keep track *in two separate places* of what each position stands for (what's the fifth variable, the sixth variable, etc.), and always keep them in sync -- and that's just one of the problems.

So use a dictionary, change `load()` to return a dictionary as well, and it all boils down to how to pass and copy dictionaries; for which there are many concise solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method to drive the process as illustrated by the `attrs_from_dict()` method shown below. Done this way, the `load()` method effectively determines what attributes are added by way of the keys in the dictionary it returns.

```
class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs_from_dict(self.load())

    def attrs_from_dict(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def load(self):
        return dict(first=1, second=2, third=3, mapping=dict(ans=42))


runner = Runner()

print(vars(runner))  # -> {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3, 'mapping': {'ans': 42}}
```